# js-xlsx - get particular rows of excel sheet

Tags: javascript, node.js, excel, xlsx, js-xlsx

I have an Excel sheet which has 500 rows. I am trying to get the rows from 101 to 200.

I have searched in google, and I have found an example to get starting rows, e.g. 1 to 100 or 1 to 1000, or even 1 to any number.

But I haven't found any code to get rows from mth row to nth row (Here 'm' and 'n' can be any number eg m=101 to n=200)

Below is the code which I have found to get first 100 rows:

```
  let workbook = XLSX.readFile('./files/uploaded_files/testfile.xlsx', {sheetRows: 100})
  const wsname = workbook.SheetNames[0];
  const ws = workbook.Sheets[wsname];
  var exceldata = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(ws);
```

Even if there is any other module to get the rows in between, I would like to know if there is any ?

Answer (score 5):

Using a smaller example of:

[image]

There are several options:

You can use your current approach and `slice` the array returned from `sheet_to_json` e.g.

```
// option 1
const maxRow = 6;
const minRow = 3;
const wb = XLSX.readFile("./Book1.xlsx", {sheetRows: maxRow});
const ws = wb.Sheets[wb.SheetNames[0]];
let data = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(ws);
data = data.slice(minRow <= 2 ? 0 : minRow - 2);
console.log(data);
```

It's `minRow - 2` to account for 1 row being headers and that the other 1 is to include row 3, not exclude it. This produces:

```
[
  { a: 4, b: 5, c: 6 },
  { a: 7, b: 8, c: 9 },
  { a: 10, b: 11, c: 12 },
  { a: 13, b: 14, c: 15 }
]
```

Another option is to combine use of the `range` and `header` (see [here](https://docs.sheetjs.com/#json)) options. `range` allows you to control what range is considered by `sheet_to_json` and `header` is used to define the keys used in the output array of objects.

You can use this after importing the whole file or continue to use the `sheetRows` option as well e.g.:

```
// option 2
const importRange = "A3:F6";
const headers = ["a", "b", "c"];
const wb = XLSX.readFile("./Book1.xlsx"); // not using sheetRows
const ws = wb.Sheets[wb.SheetNames[0]];
const data = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(ws, {range: importRange, header: headers});
console.log(data);
```

Which produces:

```
[
  { a: 4, b: 5, c: 6 },
  { a: 7, b: 8, c: 9 },
  { a: 10, b: 11, c: 12 },
  { a: 13, b: 14, c: 15 }
]
```

Noting that if you omit the `headers` option then the output is:

```
[
  { '4': 7, '5': 8, '6': 9 },
  { '4': 10, '5': 11, '6': 12 },
  { '4': 13, '5': 14, '6': 15 }
]
```

Because the values in row 3 become the new default headers (which I think you probably don't want).

Finally, if you don't know the headers in advance you can just get an array of arrays and figure the headers out later:

```
// option 3
const importRange = "A3:F6";
const headers = 1; 
const wb = XLSX.readFile("./Book1.xlsx"); // not using sheetRows
const ws = wb.Sheets[wb.SheetNames[0]];
const data = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(ws, {range: importRange, header: headers});
console.log(data);
```

Which produces:

```
[ 
  [ 4, 5, 6 ],
  [ 7, 8, 9 ],
  [ 10, 11, 12 ],
  [ 13, 14, 15 ] 
]
```